# How can I replace the floppy drive mechanism in a A-1011/CD-1411

Tags: amiga, floppy-drive, amiga-cdtv

I have a Commodore CD-1411 external floppy drive which I connect to a CDTV. Unfortunately it is not reading any disks reliably anymore despite cleaning the heads.
Inside I found a Chinon FB-354 rev D drive, but with a twist: it seems like Commodore got a custom drive with a direct connection to the DB-23 cable (PJ1), instead of typical 34-pin data + 4-pin power combo that I see on other FB-354 drives. The pads for the standard interface (PJ7) don't seem to be populated at all.

I have seen rev Ds on eBay with the standard interface - if I bought one of those and swapped the logic boards around (see PJ2 on the closeup photo), would that work?

[image: Chinon FB-354 rev D PCB with custom commodore connector]
[image: closeup of the logic board]
[image: Chinon FB-354 rev D nameplate and amiga 23 pin interface]

Comment: Are there any dedicated Amiga hardware sites?

Comment: @RonJohn I had hopes that _this_ website would be a place for people actually using old computers getting help, but hypothetical what-if questions seems to have taken over

Comment: @pipe I've seen quite a few such questions answered here, and if it was a C64 question it might have been answered.

Comment: @pipe Still, in general, a specialist site is more likely to have an answer than a generalist site... they're just harder to find for a lot of niches.